# How to align ImageView with set-width text field

Tags: android

I'm having a lot of issues trying to get this layout to work.  Im my list, I want rows with a name (TextView), icon (ImageView), and status (TextView).  But I want the status to be right aligned and a fixed character width (20), and the icon to match the height of the status and be to the left of it.  This is so that when I have many rows, the icons all align regardless of what the status is.

[image: desired layout]

I can't get any layout to accomplish this, I've tried setting `minEms` of status to 20 but then it ignores gravity for some reason.  Here's what I have so far but this way the icons don't align because they stay to the left of the status regardless of number of characters.  The reason for the inner LinearLayout is so that I can set ImageView's height to `match_parent` and be same height as text.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/row"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="testing a really really really really really long name"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="right">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_status" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is max txt size" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this layout.

Change the height of the parent to change child view heights.

Also note the weightSum="100"
The layout weight of name TextView is set at 70 so it will take up 70% of the screen width.  Make whatever changes you want just make sure the total weight of the children add up to the weightSum.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/row"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="10" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="7"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="testing a really really really really really long name" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_status" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/status"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:text="This is max txt size"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</LinearLayout>
```